# How to prevent inkscape from changing path when importing svg file?

Tags: svg, inkscape

I've manually coded an svg file that works fine in my browser.  I want to import it into inkscape as a base to do other stuff with it, but whenever I try to import it, inkscape changes my path completely.  By that I mean it alters some of d attribute points. Here's an example:

I coded:

```
   <div className="svg-container">
       <svg
        viewBox="-2 -25 200 600"
        preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      >
        <g fill="#fadfd4"><path d="     M 100, 40     L100,0C114.9116882446, 0, 127, 17.908610008, 127, 40,C127, 62.091389992, 114.9116882446, 80, 100, 80,       L118, 70              Q110, 80             120, 87.5           L130, 90     L140, 92.5     L150, 95     Q165, 105      165, 110     L170, 120           Q172.5, 140      175, 160            C175, 185     170, 165     175, 182.5           L182.5, 260         L182.5, 290   L162.5, 315   L165, 285   L157.5, 305   L157.5, 280   L167.5, 260         L155, 190   L150, 127.5          150, 150    145, 175    147.5, 190    155, 230       157.5, 250 160, 285 150, 320 140, 380 137.5, 385 142.5, 410 127.5, 470 127.5, 485 140, 520           110, 530     112.5, 485     105, 380     102.5, 370     100, 320     100, 290      L100,0C85.0883117554, 0,     73, 17.908610008,     73, 40,C73, 62.091389992,     85.0883117554, 80,     100, 80,       L82, 70              Q90, 80             80, 87.5           L70, 90     L60, 92.5     L50, 95     Q35, 105      35, 110     L30, 120           Q27.5, 140      25, 160            C25, 185     30, 165     25, 182.5           L17.5, 260         L17.5, 290   L37.5, 315   L35, 285   L42.5, 305   L42.5, 280   L32.5, 260         L45, 190   L50, 127.5          50, 150    55, 175    52.5, 190    45, 230       42.5, 250 40, 285 50, 320 60, 380 62.5, 385 57.5, 410 72.5, 470 72.5, 485 60, 520           90, 530     87.5, 485     95, 380     97.5, 370     100, 320     100, 290      100, 40     z      " style="fill: rgb(250, 223, 212); stroke: none; stroke-width: 1px;">
</path></g></svg></div>
```

Again, this is saved to svg file and it displays fine in my browser.  But when I import this svg into inkscape it just displays as a vertical line.  When I look at the XML Editor, the path has been changed to this:

```
path: M 104.86991,153.79167 V 76.449038
```

Why is this happening? It seems as if inkscape "reads" an svg and tries to optimize it in some way?  Is there a way I can prevent inkscape from altering the path and just import it as it is?  I'm pretty new at svg. Am I doing something wrong?  Please don't tell me not to program svg, I need to do this for other reasons.

Comment: Please be precise in your description. Does "changes my path" mean "changes the value of the `d` attribute of a `<path>` element, or did you mean some apparent change in rendering the path, or something completely different? Probably it would be easier to understand what is happening if you posted relevant parts of the file and what Inkscape's XML editor makes of it.

Comment: I altered my original question

Comment: Your path contains syntax errors: The use of commas is only allowed to separate numbers, but not to separate numbers from command letters. Seems that browsers are more forgiving in that regard than Inkscape.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ccprog for finding the error in my code.  Turns out Inkscape is less forgiving about commas than browsers are, for some reason.  Make sure you only have commas between numbers, and not before a command code.